# Was Captain Jean-Luc Picard an asexual?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard, sexuality

I'm currently on Season 3 of *Star Trek: The Next Generation* (thanks Netflix!), and I have been wondering since almost the first episode if Picard is asexual/aromantic rather than just awkward.

I am well aware that in future episodes/seasons he meets someone and engages in a romantic relationship, but there is a spectrum for asexuality which permits things of that sort as well as having sex and children.

Not every guy has to be as promiscuous as the infamous space-lover, Riker, but Picard seems to have an aversion to all things intimate (whether romantic or platonic, but that's another thing..).

So is he, or isn't he?

Comment: *sigh* Can't really tell if this is a decent question, or just another attempt to slap a label on a character (we get plenty).  What makes you think he's asexual rather than, say, highly responsible and focused on his duties and his ship, which is something the show portrays quite regularly?  Other than, he's not Riker?

Comment: Over the course of 7 years we see him in (evidently sexual) relationships with Vash, Dr Crusher, Eline, Marta, Nella and several others.

Answer (score 12):

### TL;dr; No, absolutely not.

Over the course of the show we see Picard in heterosexual relationships with no less than seven women;

- **Vash** ([TNG: Captain's Holiday](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Captain%27s_Holiday_(episode)))
- **Dr Beverly Crusher** ([TNG: All Good Things](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Good_Things..._(episode)))
- **Eline** ([TNG: The Inner Light](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Inner_Light_(episode)))
- **Jenice** ([TNG: We'll Always Have Paris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/We%27ll_Always_Have_Paris_(episode)))
- **Marta Batanides** ([TNG: Tapestry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tapestry_(episode)))
- **Nella Darren** ([TNG: Lessons](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lessons_(episode)))

This seems a pretty respectable number for a chap in his 50s and represents about one lady bedded per season (albeit some are in flashback, under the influence of mind-bending drugs or temporal anomalies). Apparently he even had something of a reputation as a *lady's man* in his younger days, dating multiple women at the same time.

> **PICARD:** *That woman's name [the one who slapped him] was... Corlina. I was supposed to take her to dinner... on this night...*
> (beat) *But then she found out that...* (embarrassed) *I'd made a
> second date with another woman... named Penny. Corlina was... somewhat
> upset.*
>
> **Q:** *I'm impressed. I had no idea you could be such a cad.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Tapestry](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/241.txt)</sup></sub>

---

We also see his deepest, fondest desire in [Generations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations) when he's inside the Nexus, described by Guinas as like being

> "inside joy"

His bliss evidently includes having a wife.

And in [Insurrection](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Insurrection) he begins a relationship with Anij, highlighting that he's

> "always been attracted to older women"

Comment: This is right. Picard is definitely heterosexual. What Picard is *not*, however, is a playboy or casual sex fanatic, at least not to the extent as Kirk or Riker. *Generations* shows that Picard is longing for a long term relationship leading to a large family, something that he never actually found.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - Of course it's right. I wrote it :-)

Comment: Asexuality deals with sexual activity rather than orientation. The fact that he dated women and engaged in relationships does not mean he isn't Asexual. But thanks for your input.